# Ruby running process in the background

Tags: ruby, multithreading, console, console-application, fibers

I am attempting to write a small console application to play mp3s. The mp3 playing will be handled by an external binary, say mpg123, whilst the playback control, playlists etc will be implemented as a curses console app.

Say I create a "playlist" object which has many tracks added to it. When I play a track, I need to call the binary in the background whilst allowing the UI to be responsive. I also need to be able to skip to the next track etc.

I assume I need to use a Thread or Fiber for this? How do I control the Thread?

I've not done any threaded Ruby programming before.

Does anyone have a simple example of how to get started with this?

Comment: This article helped me get my head around ruby threads https://blog.engineyard.com/2011/a-modern-guide-to-threads